# Can ClickOnce deployment technique be used in combination with Systems Management Server (SMS)?

Tags: clickonce

Can ClickOnce deployment technique be used in combination with Systems Management Server (SMS)?
What I have seen so far is that we have to publish an application on Web Server, FTP or network to be eligible for clickonce deployment. But our organization has policy of distributing applications through SMS only. Are there any ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No, ClickOnce can not be used in combination with SMS.